# FFMPEG brightening .exr image sequence results in 'washed out' video

Tags: ffmpeg

Hoping some FFMPEG experts can help with properly brightening an image sequence.

The sequence is low key, objects against a black background.
I need to lighten it so that only the objects appear brighter
The following is my attempt to increase the gamma but the result appears 'washed out'. ie saturation or color is removed

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.%03d.exr -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -crf 17  -vf lutyuv=y=gammaval(0.5) output.mov
```

also tried 
lutyuv=y=val*4
to increase brightness but then my black background appears grey.

I guess I need the equivalent of a custom curve that holds the blacks and only lightens the midtones-highlights.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the curves filter

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.%03d.exr -vf curves=strong_contrast output.mov
```

or via manual adjustment

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.%03d.exr -vf curves=m='0/0 0.25/0.25 0.65/0.8 0.95/1' output.mov
```

Each `x/y` pair is input->output assignment with values normalized to `[0,1]`.

The LUT expression can also be set to proportionally adjust value e.g.

```
lutyuv=y='gammaval(1-(1.2/2.2)*(max((val-64),0)/256))'
```

This will leaves values upto 64 intact and then proportionally scale up higher values.